# What date format is 1376172000?

Tags: date, format, standards

On a site I visit regularly, I noticed that, when I select a particular date (11 august 2013 in this case), `?date=1376172000` is added to the url in the address bar.

What format or standard is this date?

Comment: Looks like a UNIX timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely "units from epoch" e.g. in unix, seconds since 00:00 GMT 01 Jan 1970.  Other systems / sites could use different units and a different starting time (epoch)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a Unix timestamp.See http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is time in seconds defined as the number of seconds which have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

It is a UNIX Time Stamp
you can Convert this to human readable format
`<?php`
`$timestamp=$_GET['date']; // which gives 1376172000`
`echo gmdate("Y-m-d\ H:i:s", $timestamp);`
`?>`